# Finding Largest Element of a Matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, max

I am using R for the first time and need to write a function that takes in a matrix with 2 columns. For example

```
col1 col2
  2   0.2
  3   0.2
  4   0.3
  5   0.1
  6   0.2
```

Based on which number is highest in col2 (which is 0.3), I need to return the corresponding number in col1 (which is 4). How can I go about doing this in R?

Comment: `dat$col1[which.max(dat$col2)]` for a `data.frame` or `dat[,"col1"][which.max(dat[,"col2"])]` for a `matrix`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could also `order` the dataset by the second column and get the first element

```
df1[order(-df1[,'col2']),1][1]
#[1] 4
```